# Python: How do you make a variable = 1 and it still being that way in a different def block? (For a game)

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, global

I have a question. How do you get variables to stay defined in even when your in a different def functions? I have a function that serves a purpose of seeing how many `AIs a user wants` and for example if they choose 'One' for the amount of AIs they wanted `AI1 would be equal 1`. Here is where AI1 is defined:

```
def AISection():#Same as line 1
    global AI1, AI2, AI3
    print("How many AIs do you want to play with?\nChoices:\n1. One\n2. Two\n3. Three")
    #Asks user next question.
    while(True):
    #Same as line 4.
        UserInput = input("Answer goes here:")
        #same as line 6
        if(UserInput in ['ONE', 'One', 'one']):
        #Same as line 8
            AI1 = 1
            #Only AI1 will be activated.
            break
            #Same as line
```

So if they `choose 'One'` only `AI1 will be equal to 1`. Then once this happens, The user will be able to select how many cards they want. This is based off of how many AIs they wanted activated So, in the previous paragraph `One` would be selected and so they will have the options of choosing from 3 different card amounts in the code below:

```
def CardsSection():#Same as line 1
    global AI1, AI2, AI3#Makes sure the AIs are equal to something
    print("How many cards do you want in your hand?")
    #Asks the user for an amount of cards the users wants.
    if(AI1 == 1) and (AI2 == 2):
    #If they choose 2 AIs.
        print("Choices:\n1. Four\n2. Six\n3. Eight")
        #This is so an even amount of cards will be distributed from the deck.
    elif(AI1 == 1) or (AI1 == 1) and (AI3 == 3):
    #If they choose 1 AI or 3 AIs.
        print("Choices:\n1. Five\n2. Seven\n3. Nine")
        #Same is line 68.
```

But when I ran the code It got to the `def CardsSection` (the section after the AISection where AI1 was definedin). Then gave me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 81, in <module>
  File "python", line 68, in CardsSection
NameError: name 'AI1' is not defined
```

The problem is I defined AI1 = 1 but my code wont recognize it. I think it is because it was defined in a different def. I thought if I used the global "Module" that whatever I put AI1, AI2 and AI3 equal to they would be like that regardless of what def Function I'm in. How can I make it so that wherever I set AI1, AI2, and AI3 equal to (In this case AISection), they will be that way regardless of where I am? Here is the full code i have so far:

```
def StartSection():#The starting section.
    print("Do you want to play?\nChoices:\n1. Yes\n2. No")
    #Asks the user a question.
    while(True):
        #Loops if user doesn't answer properly. 
        UserInput = input("Answer goes here:")
        #Prompts the users.
        if(UserInput in ['YES', 'Yes', 'yes']): 
        #If user says yes.
            print("Great! Now choose your 'AI Settings'.")
            #Praises the user & tells user about next prompt.
            break
            #Stops the loop. Continues to next prompt.
        elif(UserInput in ['NO', 'No', 'no']): 
            #Else, if User says no.
            print("Bye bye!")
            #Farewells to the user.
            quit() 
            #Ends Code.
        else:
        #Else user types neither 'Yes' or 'No'.
            print("That is not a choice! Please try again.")
            #Tells user to choose again.
            print("Here are the choices:\n1. Yes\n2. No")
            #Tells user their choices again; goes back to start.
StartSection()#Ends the section of code.
def AISection():#Same as line 1
    global AI1, AI2, AI3
    print("How many AIs do you want to play with?\nChoices:\n1. One\n2. Two\n3. Three")
    #Asks user next question.
    while(True):
    #Same as line 4.
        UserInput = input("Answer goes here:")
        #same as line 6
        if(UserInput in ['ONE', 'One', 'one']):
        #Same as line 8
            AI1 = 1
            #Only AI1 will be activated.
            break
            #Same as line 12
        elif(UserInput in ['TWO', 'Two', 'two']):
        #Same as line 14
            AI1 = 1
            AI2 = 2
            #AI1 and AI2 are activated. AI3 is not activated.
            break
            #Same as line 12
        elif(UserInput in ['THREE', 'Three', 'three']):
        #Same as line 14
            AI1 = 1
            AI2 = 2
            AI3 = 3
            #All 3 AIs are activated.
            break
            #Same as line 12
        else:
            print("That is not a choice! Pleasse try again.")
            #Same as line 22
            print("Here are your choices:\n1. One\n2. Two\n3. Three")
            #Same as line 24
    print("You selested %s AIs" % (UserInput[0].upper()+UserInput[1::1].lower()))
    #Tells the user that what they select while keeping it in a upper-lower case fashion.
AISection()#Same as line 26
def CardsSection():#Same as line 1
    global AI1, AI2, AI3#Makes sure the AIs are equal to something
    print("How many cards do you want in your hand?")
    #Asks the user for an amount of cards the users wants.
    if(AI1 == 1) and (AI2 == 2):
    #If they choose 2 AIs.
        print("Choices:\n1. Four\n2. Six\n3. Eight")
        #This is so an even amount of cards will be distributed from the deck.
    elif(AI1 == 1) or (AI1 == 1) and (AI3 == 3):
    #If they choose 1 AI or 3 AIs.
        print("Choices:\n1. Five\n2. Seven\n3. Nine")
        #Same is line 68.
    else:
        print("Something didn't go right!")
        #If they happened to choose neither 1, 2, or 3 AIs.
        return StartSection()
        #Returns them basck to start.
CardsSection()
```

I hope this helps :).

Comment: You should include the full code or atleast enough of it to reproduce the problem. But try putting `A1 = A2 = A3 = None` at the top of your code below the imports

Comment: @Keatinge okay hold on

Comment: @BradTheBrutalitist I've reconstructed a very basic view of your code, does that solve your problem?

Comment: @PopeyGilbert Yes thank you for helping me

Comment: You can make your life a lot easier and improve your code by passing the state your functions need as parameters instead of using globals. Then the scope problem goes away and the program is much easier to reason about and maintain.

Comment: @pvg I don't want to say I'm inexperienced with parameters but, I don't really use them that often because, I trained myself to do this differently. Perhaps you could show me an example and I might catch on.

Comment: It's a pretty fundamental aspect of design and SO comments are probably not a great place to explain the merits of the concept - you'll find it in any tutorial text on Python programming and programming in general. You could also check out something like Peter Norvig's udacity course https://www.udacity.com/course/design-of-computer-programs--cs212

The basic idea is that passing in the state makes it clear what the inputs of your function are and avoids errors that arise due to the difficulty of managing, modifying and reasoning about global state.

Comment: @pvg thanks for the link. It will help alot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are facing a [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) problem, with the fact that although you are defining it as global, you haven't defined it outside the function to begin with.  If you define the three variables outside any of your functions, then your program appears to work:

```
def AISection():
    global AI1, AI2, AI3
    AI1 = 0
    AI2 = 0
    AI3 = 0
    print("How many AIs do you want to play with?\nChoices:\n1. One\n2. Two\n3. Three")
    while True:
        UserInput = input("Answer goes here:")
        if UserInput.lower() == "one":
            AI1 += 1
            break
```

---

```
def CardsSection():
    global AI1, AI2, AI3
    print("How many cards do you want in your hand?")
    if AI1 == 1 and AI2 == 2:
        print("Choices:\n1. Four\n2. Six\n3. Eight")
    elif AI1 == 1 or AI1 == 1 and AI3 == 3:
          print("Choices:\n1. Five\n2. Seven\n3. Nine")
```

Also note, although this isn't code review, I'd highly suggest using UserInput.lower() == "one" instead of your list checking, it will be more efficient and accept more answers ("oNe" for example, if a user ever wanted to input that).

Comment: Okay thank you for the helpful feedback let me try this

Comment: I actually instead of making AI1 in the function I made AI1 += 1 So it would equal one but this helped fix the problem

Comment: @BradTheBrutalitist Apologies for not understanding, but I'm glad it helped fix the underlying issue :)!

Comment: You don't have to define it outside the function, defining it inside the function works just fine.

Comment: @PopeyGilbert and thanks for the UserInput.lower() it really helps :).

Comment: @BoltKey does actually have a point.  You can remove the AI1, AI2, AI3 = ... and the code will still work.  I honestly thought Python just change the local pointers instead of actually changing the global pointers.  I'll update the answer :)

Comment: @PopeyGilbert Yeah It does work both ways but, In time it might get crowded having everything outside of the defs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not defining the variables AI1, AI2 or AI3 in AISection(). You need to set them to 0 there, else they are not defined.

```
def AISection():
    global AI1, AI2, AI3
    AI1 = 0
    AI2 = 0
    AI3 = 0
    print("How many AIs do you want to play with?\nChoices:\n1. One\n2. Two\n3. Three")
    while True:
        UserInput = input("Answer goes here:")
        if UserInput.lower() == "one":
            AI1 = 1
            break
```

Comment: This also works thank you for helping I appreciate it. :)